# How can I import a class from a external script using Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to use a library from a CDN (I can't save the file and use it in the src).

```
<script src="https://secure.mlstatic.com/sdk/javascript/v1/mercadopago.js"></script>
```

I can add this line in `index.html`, but I need to use a class from that library in one of my components.

```
Mercadopago.setPublishableKey(myKey);
```

Doing so gives me the error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/carrito.component.ts(274,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Mercadopago'.
```

I know I haven't declared or imported `Mercadopago` in my component. How can I do this?

Comment: Add `declare var Mercadopago: any` to your component.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a global variable use `declare` in your `src/app/components/carrito.component.ts`

**carrito.component.ts**

```
declare var Mercadopago: any
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is running in a browser...

When the external source is loaded in the browser, any globally accessible objects/functions/definitions will be set on the `window` object and you can simply access them via `window["MyClass"]`. Or in your specific case:

```
window["Mercadopago"].setPublishableKey(myKey);
```